# Should we make [politeness] a synonym of [etiquette]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I would suggest the synonym, but there aren't too many of these questions, and I don't have the required votes in the tags to suggest it.  If someone else thinks it's a good idea, could they suggest it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Although I see kiamlaluno's distinction, that doesn't mean [politeness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness) and [etiquette](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) are worth their own tags, considering the relatively few number of questions that we get about them and the considerable overlap between the two tags.
2. I have created the tag synonym in the [etiquette](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) -> [politeness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politeness) direction given that the latter is broader and already has more questions. <s>but not yet merged the tags</s>.
3. <s>If there are no further objections, I will merge the tags within the next day or two.</s> The tags have been merged. If you have strong opinions against this, the merge and synonym can always be undone, but please make a good argument for it.

Comment: Do it! Plz! ---

Answer (score 0):

To me they don't seem to be always synonyms, as I could be polite without following a "customary code of polite behavior in society or among members of a particular profession or group."

Comment: Very fine line there, IMHO.  Etiquette is almost always determined by politeness.